# Using Import in Python open another Python script only works one time around

Tags: python, import, python-3.6

I'm just playing around with some stuff in Pygame, making a little game. I decided to make a separate menu script and a main game script, and I'm using

```
import script2
```

In the first script, then

```
import script1
```

In the second one, so that when you press a button in the first, it opens the second, and closing the second opens the first.

It works the first time, script1 opens script2 and script2 closes to script1, however attempting to open script 2 a second time doesn't work. I don't understand why this is happening, and if anyone could explain I'd be grateful.

Comment: Can you show some code as to how you open and close stuff?

Comment: @Sweeper I actually just tested it using only (And literally **only**, it's two lines in each script, a print statement to show the script ran, and the Import statement.) the import command in two different scripts, and it still does it without any extra factors. I think I actually figured out why it happens, Import probably doesn't work a second time because the script is already Imported, and can't be **re**imported. Although, a work around would still be nice if you have an idea?

Comment: Obviously you can't run a script multiple times using import. You can declare a function in a script and call that multiple times.

Comment: If you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on that checkmark!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your comment, I think I kind of get what you want to do. You are trying to use `import` as a way to run another script multiple times. But that's not what imports are for.

When you want to run a piece code multiple times i.e. reuse it, you can declare a *function*.

```
# in script1.py
def my_function():
    print("Hello")
    print("World")
```

Now in script2.py, you can import script1 and then call the function:

```
import script1
script1.my_function()
```

Running script2 will produce this

```
Hello
World
```